# reorder ul based on li class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sure this is very simple but sadly I am not seeing it right now. I have a menu with list items. some of them have a class col-1 and the others have a class of col-2. I am trying to loop through each list item and separate them into two new `<ul>'s` and then replace this `<ul>` with the two new `<ul>'s`.

here is my current html:

```
<ul>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27594" class="col-1 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-26963" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27030" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27595" class="col-2 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27220" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-25885" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-25922" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#"><a href="#">Blah</a></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the output I would like to achieve:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="col-1">
      <li id="nav-menu-item-27594" class="col-1 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
        <a href="#">Blah</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-26963" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
        <a href="#">Blah</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-27030" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
        <a href="#">Blah</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="col-2">
      <li id="nav-menu-item-27595" class="col-2 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
        <a href="#">Blah</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-27220" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
        <a href="#">Blah</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-25885" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
        <a href="#">Blah</a>
      </li>
      <li id="nav-menu-item-25922" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
        <a href="#"><a href="#">Blah</a></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I know I need to replace the contents of the ul with the new li's but I don't think I am even using the right approach at this point.

Comment: I posted a possible solution down below. Kindly let me know if that works for you (or if I misunderstood your requirement).

Comment: I am working with it right now. I am not getting the same results. I did this `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul > li.col-1').appendTo('ul.first');` `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul > li.col-2').appendTo('ul.two');` `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul').html('<ul class="first"></ul><ul class="two"></ul>');` and it comes up empty

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTML structure? Where are these elements `.sub-menu-columns .second .inner` located exactly?

Comment: `.sub-menu-columns .second .inner` lead to the `ul` I am trying to manipulate. They are other ul's and li's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```js
$('ul')
  .append($('<li>').append($('<ul class="col-1">').append($('ul .col-1'))))
  .append($('<li>').append($('<ul class="col-2">').append($('ul .col-2'))))
```

```css
ul {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 4px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27594" class="col-1 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-26963" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27030" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27595" class="col-2 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27220" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-25885" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-25922" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#"><a href="#">Blah</a></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is close. I need to replace the original ul with the two new ones so it looks like this. `<ul><li><ul class="col-1"></ul><ul class="col-2"></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: @Jason, I've answered exactly what you asked in your question. Your new requirement looks misleading to me.

Comment: I am sorry Kosh if I was misleading in any way. I like your approach. If you look at my desired HTML output you will see that it has a parent ul with two new ul's inside it. (I forgot to add the li)

Comment: Thank Kosh, I liked your approach but in the end it was the same amount of code and @jom was the first to respond

Comment: @Jason, jom uses unnecessary HTML code for new `ul` and ends up with an empty old `ul` above the new one. But it's up to you what to accept and use.

Comment: Ok I am eating lunch but will try your newest approach when I am finished. FYI: you are correct Jom uses unnecessary html but I did not follow his complete approach

Comment: ok @kosh, after playing with your approach I want to change the outcome a bit. currently I am doing this `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner').append($('<ul class="col-1">').append($('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner .col-1'))).append($('<ul class="col-2">').append($('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner .col-2')))` I removed the ul from the first line. I would now like to see the two ul's inside the `<div class="inner">` what I posted does that but it adds an extra empty ul. I am trying to clear out the .inner div and fill it with the two new ul's

Comment: I figured it out using `$(".sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul:not([class*='cols'])").remove();`

Comment: @Jason, you might return to the very first edition of my answer which splits `ul`. You would just need to add a class to the initial one.

Comment: @Jason, like this: `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul').addClass('col-1').after($('<ul class="col-2">').append($('ul .col-2')))`

Comment: That is duplicating col-2 @kosh

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. I needed to add `.sub-menu-columns .second .inner` to the last  `ul` thank @kosh

Answer (score 0):

Try `jQuery.appendTo()`. No explicit looping and temp arrays necessary, since this will **move** the matching elements from one container to another.

```js
$('ul > li.col-1').appendTo('ul.parent > ul.first');

$('ul > li.col-2').appendTo('ul.parent > ul.second');
```

```css
ul.first {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul.second {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li id="nav-menu-item-27594" class="col-1 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-26963" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27030" class="col-1 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27595" class="col-2 col-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-27220" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-25885" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#">Blah</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-25922" class="col-2 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
    <a href="#"><a href="#">Blah</a></a>
  </li>

</ul>

<ul class="parent">
  <ul class="first"></ul>
  <ul class="second"></ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think I got it with this: `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul').append('<ul class="first"></ul><ul class="two"></ul>')`
    
   `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul > li.col-1').appendTo('ul.first');`

    `$('.sub-menu-columns .second .inner ul > li.col-2').appendTo('ul.two');`